# Scroll bar on Mac RStudio blocks view of code

Tags: r, macos, scroll, rstudio

My scroll bar in RStudio keeps blocking the view of my code in RStudio, even as I try changing settings for Scroll Bar Behaviour in Mac System Preferences. It doesn't move or disappear, but stay put, overlapping and in front of my code. See picture below for example.

Solutions in other threads point to changing the setting for the Scroll Bar Behaviour to Automatic. However, since that hasn't solved it, for me at least, I wanted to ask you for advice on how to fix this.

I'm running macOS Mojave, version 10.14.6, on a Macbook, having just updated RStudio.

[image: Scroll bar blocks view of code in Mac RStudio]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some GitHub chatter [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/1953), sounds like this is bug between macOS Mojave, RStudio and some software underpinnings to RStudio called Qt. I hope RStudio will release a fix for this, but in the meantime a temporary fix can be achieved by

System Preferences >> General >> Show scroll bars: When scrolling

[image]